# Error GlideDrawable when using Glide Library

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

But when I use

```
    Glide.with(ctx)
            .load(new File(items.get(position).getCompletePath()))
            .crossFade()
            .listener(new RequestListener<File, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(holder.thumbnailImageView);
```

**GlideDrawable** gives an error

```
error: cannot find symbol class GlideDrawable
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

I'm using

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575249/android-studio-cannot-find-symbol-class-glidedrawable

Comment: Any update Drawable also not woking in the latest 4.11.0